# change text when page has loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a firefox extension and I want to change some text when the page finished loading. for example I need something like:

```
page.onload(changetext())
```

I tried window.load() document.load() and document.readyState but they all only work half the time. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) or [`load` *event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) ?

Comment: The page probably is dynamically updated so you'll need MutationObserver.